# Problem finding Centre of Mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, calculus

**My Question:** For finding the Center of Mass ($COM$) of a hollow cone, why do we use its area to define its elemental mass ($dm$) and not its volume, which we use to find the $COM$ of a solid cone.

The formula I use for finding the center of mass of an object is:

$$\frac{\int_{o}^{h}dmy}{\int_{o}^{h}dm}$$

Comment: For a solid cone, the mass is dependent on volume , for a hollow, it is dependent on the surface area.

Comment: The hollow cone does not have a 'volume,' at least in the theoretical sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your mass element for a hollow cone will be dm = ρ(2πr)dl where  ρ is the surface mass density, dl is a segment of length on the surface measured from the apex, and r is measured from the central axis to dl.  If y is measured along the axis from the apex, then r = y tan(θ) and dy = dl cos(θ).